# Sometimes pandas read_sql_query returns empty

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the below code in Python/pandas and sometimes I get the data and sometimes it returns an empty DataFrame. Not sure what is going wrong here but it seems some bug if I am passing multiple params in `read_sql_query`:

```
query = "Select [C1], [LIFE_CYCLE] from TBL_NAME with(NOLOCK) where C1 = ? and (LIFE_CYCLE = ? or LIFE_CYCLE = ?)"

result = pd.read_sql_query(query, cnxn, params={'ABC','Account Live','Onboarding in progress'})
```

When I changed this as below, it works fine every time:

```
query = "Select [C1], [LIFE_CYCLE] from TBL_NAME with(NOLOCK) where C1 = ? and (LIFE_CYCLE = 'Account Live' or LIFE_CYCLE = 'Onboarding in progress')"

result = pd.read_sql_query(query, cnxn, params={'ABC'})
```

Versions: pandas==1.2.4, pyodbc==4.0.30

Comment: You put curly brackets in your first `read_sql_query` line.  What that a typo?  If that's real, that's the problem.  It needs to be a `(tuple)` or a `[list]`.  Using curly brackets makes it a `set`, which is going to get sorted.

Comment: @TimRoberts: then close as typo

Comment: try change `params={'ABC','Account Live','Onboarding in progress'}` to `params=('ABC','Account Live','Onboarding in progress')`

Comment: @TimRoberts then it should not return data sometimes.. it should return Empty DataFrame every time, right?

Comment: No, sometimes they will be in the right order.  I assume it's not "ABC" every single time.